# How to Bring Android Activity to the Foreground and Detect if its in background?

Tags: android

I have a callback inside an Activity which is called by a remote service.  I fire a Toast when it gets called so, i know its getting called but its in the background, so I need a way from within the activity to make it go to the foreground.  How can this be done.  Also detect if I am in Foreground or not.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Android Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) you can detect if your Activity is in the background. To return your Activity to the foreground use a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) in the [Status Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html). You can forcibly move your Activity to the foreground by firing an Intent but that can cause frustration and annoyance to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Just call startActivity with the right Intent.

Edit: Forgot to say, that it'a a very confusing behaviour, if an Activity brings itself to the front. The user could do something else and be disturbed. Set a notification instead.